# Two conversions to base three yield different results

Tags: arithmetic, number-systems

[image]

How are there two different conversion results for the same bases? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Yes, you are. (Please lay out the calculations in your own words and with the build-in formatting (Markdown + LaTeX).)

Comment: Please don't use images as the main content of your question.  Not only is it a bit lazy, it is not accessible to readers with visual disabilities and it is not findable through search.  I suggest you edit your question to replace all use of images with Latex.

Comment: As @Per Manne observed, your first computation is in base-10. You would arrive at the correct answer if you had done all the calculations in base-5, though most people aren't practiced in base-5 arithmetic division.

Answer (score 3):

The second attempt is correct. In the first attempt, you have computed $(432)_{10}$, not $(432)_5$.